# Problems w/ Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

This is my first post here, so forgive me for stupid questioning or describing my problem not „the programmer's way“. :-)

I've added Facebook comments to my Wordpress blog. Now, I posted a test comment with another Facebook profile than the one I used to create the app.

Voila, the comment appeared on the Graph API of that site. Worked well.

I deleted the comment, but it seems as it's still visible in the Graph API of the site.

Is there any cache for deleted comments!? How can I fix that?

It's important for me to know, because I think of a contest. Users have to add captions to pictures via the Facebook commentbox.

It doesn't give me any benefit, if comments that have been deleted will remain in the Graph API.

Any solution for it? What else do you need to know what I'm talking about? :-)

Cheers,

Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete comments, that's a bit bad documented. All you can do is hide it from other users. Every fb user that is a friend of the user that posted that 'deleted' comment can see the comment as well as the user himself too (in the actual fb comments box).

Furthermore it will exist *forever* in the graph api! That's facebooks way of pushing freedom of expression!

Anyway if you delete content it doesn't sound like a fair contest to people, as they might feel objected, also not everyone will have the same chances then. A system where you can properly approve 'comments/captiions' would make way more sense. See Diskus for example.

If you wanna have the facebook comments social advertising boost though you could write all comments from the graph api into a database and then approve them manually. Another way would be just to tell users to subscribe/like your facebook page to see who's winning or to be able to win at all. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, man! Great answer, although it's not what I wanted to hear. :-)

Comment: The truth can be hard sometimes ;) welcome to SO anyway. remember to always mark the correct answer and keep on going. read the faq, thats always good :)

Comment: My suggestion: opening up a new Facebook profile (xyz) and not adding any people.

Then, it actually won't be a matter of programming, but just a matter of changing the terms and conditions of the contest. :-)

Would it be correct if I mention something like: „Only comments that have not been hidden by the submitter and are visible to xyz will take part in the contest.“?

What d'y think?

Cheers

Comment: edited my answer. a little tip, edit your question/create a new one if you need more information/answers here! the comments are not really made for discussions like that :)